# BSD sed unable to replace all ",0,"

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I know a bit about the differences between GNU sed and BSD sed. Unfortunately I don't have a linux machine, only mac is available.

I have a large data file in csv format, delimited by comma. Even the first two lines of the file is too large to post here, you can find the first two lines [here](http://pastebin.com/wyj9Begu).

I need to substitute values of 0,8,9,-999,-999.0 by "NA" because those values are codes for missing values.

I used the following sed command in bash prompt

```
sed -e 's/\-999\.?\0?/NA/g' \
    -e 's/\-999/NA/g' \
    -e 's/,9,/,NA,/g' \
    -e 's/,8,/,NA,/g' \
    -e 's/,0,/,NA,/g' \
    firsttwolines.csv
```

The result looks fine except there still exists a single `0`. How to fix it? And how to put it in a bash script? Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I'm assuming that your input contains `,0,0,`, and your output contains `,NA,0,`? If so -- this is because each replacement of `,0,` can only begin after the position where previous replacement of `,0,` leaves off.

Comment: Indeed! How to deal with `,0,0,` then?

Comment: If no value other than 0 can begin with 0, then just ',0' => ',NA'

Comment: Your code will replace 9990 with NA

Comment: @IvyLee: I don't have a BSD machine handy, so I can't test any suggestions. That's why I posted a comment rather than answer. (Of course, you could just use Perl: `perl -ne 's/(^|(?<=,))([089]|-999(\.0)?)(?=,|$)/NA/g`. Who needs sed, anyway? :-P )

Comment: @ruakh I understand there are many tools that can solve this problem, but this is part of a collaborated project so the tools are limited to what others are using. I'd like to use things like sed/awk because they are system utilities. (and this question probably doesn't exist if our team is using perl :p)

Comment: @IvyLee: Yes, which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think awk would be a better choice for this task (tested with gawk and nawk):

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i == 0 || $i == 8 || $i == 9 || $i == -999) $i = "NA" } 1' FS=, OFS=, firsttwolines.csv
```

The for-loop runs through each field and tests it for equality with the NA list, if found true the field is replaced by `NA`, note that awk converts the field to a number before testing. The `1` at the end invokes the default block `{ print $0 }`.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when dealing with CSV file format, text scanning tools such as sed, awk are poorly equipped to deal with all the corner cases. I know that you specifically asked for solution in sed, but it does not do the job well. I recommend a language that offers robust CSV file handling such as Python or Tcl (there are more, but these are what I know). Here is a solution in Python:

```
# csvreplace.py

import sys
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    infilename = sys.argv[1]
    outfilename = sys.argv[2]

    with open(infilename) as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(infile)
        csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
        na_list = ['0', '8', '9', '-999', '-999.0']
        for row in csvreader:
            row = [col in na_list and 'NA' or col for col in row]
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

You can use it in your bash script as:

```
python csvreplace.py data.csv out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed, try:

```
sed -e 's/\-999\(\.0\)*/NA/g' -e :a -e 's/,[089],/,NA,/; ta' file
```